# set and get value using Session storage for html drop down with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

Working on Session storage where in the first page I have a drop down if user select (.bap_mjr) value from the drop-down and click next button from the first page  It will redirect to the second page where I need to show an label.

First page HTML

```
  <select class="mslt_Field slt_major slt_mjr ipt_required" id="slt_mjr" name="slt_mjr">
     <option value="">Please Select</optio
     <option value="BA in Arts,Culture&Heritage Ma">BAACHM</option>
     <option id="bap_Mjr" class="bap_Mjr"  value="Bachelor of Arts in Persian">BAP</option>
     <option value="Bachelor of Bus Adminstration">BBA</option>
   </select>
```

Currently I am trying  In First Page this is my jquery code

```
$("#slt_mjr").change(function (){
                alert($(this).val());
                var dropselvalue = -1;
                if (document.getElementById("bap_Mjr").val())
                {
                    alert("check");
                    dropselvalue = 1;
                }
                if(window.sessionStorage) { 
                   sessionStorage.setItem("dropselvalue", dropselvalue);
               }
            });
```

Second page

```
<div class="pay_click">Welcome to second page</div>
```

Second page jquery code

```
var dropselvalue = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("dropselvalue"));
    if (dropselvalue != -1) {
        if (dropselvalue === 1) {
            $(".pay_click").show()
        }
        //localStorage.removeItem("CheckedRadioValue");
    }
```

The session was not stored and I am not able to get the item.

Where I am doing mistake kindly help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: so what does happen? What have you done to troubleshoot this?

Comment: @charlietfl I have tried this sessionStorage.setItem("dropselvalue", dropselvalue); but not working any luck :(

Comment: still doesn't suggest how you are troubleshooting this? Can inspect storage and do logging in browser dev tools

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you had an incomplete ending  tag, and you were using .val() on javascript, not jquery.

try this code:

html, first page:

```
<select id="slt_mjr" name="slt_mjr">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="BA in Arts,Culture&Heritage Ma">BAACHM</option>
    <option id="bap_Mjr" class="bap_Mjr" value="Bachelor of Arts in Persian">BAP</option>
    <option value="Bachelor of Bus Adminstration">BBA</option>
</select>
<a href="deleteme1.html">Link to second page</a>
```

javascript, first page:

```
$("#slt_mjr").change(function () {
        //alert($(this).val());
        var dropselvalue = -1;
        if ($("#bap_Mjr").val()) {
            dropselvalue = 1;
        }

        if (window.sessionStorage) {
            sessionStorage.setItem("dropselvalue", dropselvalue);
        }
    });
```

html, second page:

```
<button id="check">Check</button>
```

javascript, second page

```
$('#check').click(function () {
        var dropselvalue = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("dropselvalue"));
        if (dropselvalue != -1) {
            if (dropselvalue === 1) {
                alert();
            }
            //localStorage.removeItem("CheckedRadioValue");
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks for the help but where i will write the code for to display div in the second page

Comment: generally you want to put script tags at the bottom of the page, before the closing </body> tag. Just put that button on ur second page, copy the javascript into a script tag on the second page, and it should work