# How to store the drop down values selected in a session and update in the database while clicking on the submit button

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

[image: Example]

I want to choose the values from each dropdown and update in the database once I click on the "submit" button. Can anyone please tell me how to store these values in a session array and use while the button is clicked?

Comment: Submit button is on a separate page or on the same page where dropdowns are located?

Comment: I am sorry for giving incomplete information. The "submit" button is on the same page and while clicking the button I want the chose dropdown values for each row to be updated in the db. My question is how to store the drop down value for each row in a session as array?

Comment: So you don't have to store dropdowns values in session. When you click submit button. you can get the values from dropdowns using jquery and send to back-end which will save your data in a database.

Comment: you can simply get dropdown value in jquery. `$('#dropdownID option:selected').text();`

Comment: Yeah But then my concern is when I choose the dropdown value, which is allocating a hostel unit, I want the no. of occupancy to be reduced to one. I want the no. of occupancies to be reduced by one which has to be done on selecting each value. Its a risk to update that without storing in a session.

Comment: Sorry I am not clear about the requirement mention in the comment. It thinks it is still a risk not updating the database when you do the front end changes when selecting drop-down values. 
Just check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33598738/set-and-get-value-using-session-storage-for-html-drop-down-with-jquery). Maybe this will help you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you well. But on `drop` you can save value to `localStorage` (https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or `cookies` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) and on button `click` you can read values from `localStorage`/`cookies`

Comment: Yeah I tried this same method : `setUnitEventListener:function(){`
           `$(".Unit").unbind("change").bind("change",function(event){`
            `event.preventDefault();`
            ` `sessionStorage.setItem(".Unit",this.value);`
             `if(sessionStorage.getItem(".Unit")){`
                       `$(".Unit").val(sessionStorage.getItem(".Unit"));`                 But I want to do the same to store the values for each drop down selection for each row in the table.